# Android : how to pass multiple numbers to create contact page

Tags: android, android-contacts

one of function of my app is put an exist user account to contact book

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "first number");
```

its work fine in case of there is only one number 
but if i try to put another number (put another extra with same extra key) it might overwrite then first number is gone

```
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "1111");
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "2222");
```

[image: first number is gone]

*first number was overwritten

any idea ? 
Thank you very much for help and i apologize for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can specify the other number as [SECONDARY_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#SECONDARY_PHONE). This way you can insert 3 phone numbers for a contact, as there is a [TERTIARY_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#TERTIARY_PHONE) too.

Also you can specify the [PHONE_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#PHONE_TYPE) to specify the type of contact number it represents.